# mvn error--while building the project

Tags: maven

In my case all the individual modules are getting build successful but the DIST-distributable one is failed in the last giving the followin error.

Failed to execute goal on project com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.dist: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.dist:pom:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.brand:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.businesslogic.impl:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.businesslogic.api:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.channels:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.client:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.persistence:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.context:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.contract:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.ranking:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.endpoint:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.smartphone:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.services.truerest:jar:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.web-ui:war:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project:com.sybase365.mobiliser.custom.project.persistence:zip:db-scripts-ase:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.brand:aims-brand:zip:1.3.1 (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.vanilla:com.sybase365.mobiliser.vanilla.ase:jar:scriptarchive-ase:5.1.0.RELEASE (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.vanilla:com.sybase365.mobiliser.vanilla.ase:zip:dist:5.1.0.RELEASE (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging:com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging.channelmanager.engine.jmsconnection:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging:com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging.channelmanager.engine.jmspickup:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE (compile), com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging:com.sybase365.mobiliser.util.messaging.channelmanager.engine.jmsreceiver:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE (compile), org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit:jar:4.8.1 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sybase365.mobiliser.money:com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.businesslogic.bulkprocessing.handlers.transaction:jar:5.1.0.RELEASE: Could not transfer artifact com.sybase365.mobiliser.money:com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.businesslogic.bulkprocessing.handlers.transaction:pom:5.1.0.RELEASE from/to repo (https://repo.paybox.net/nexus/content/groups/public-devel): Access denied to https://repo.paybox.net/nexus/content/groups/public-devel/com/sybase365/mobiliser/money/com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.businesslogic.bulkprocessing.handlers.transaction/5.1.0.RELEASE/com.sybase365.mobiliser.money.businesslogic.bulkprocessing.handlers.transaction-5.1.0.RELEASE.pom. Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Your problem looks like this: `Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1] [ERROR]`.

Comment: YES, BUT I am running it by Admin, It should have the access. I am not sure after the successful compilation of all the modules its getting failed in DISTRIBUTABLE one..Any one please suggest..

Comment: Have correctly given the credentials within the settings.xml file?